# correct way to apply style properties to later elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add the css properties to later elements through jQuery/javascript?

here is my try: but fails:

```js
// failed
$('.yah').load(function() {
  $(this).css({ border: "2px solid red" });
});

// failed
$('.yah').ready(function() {
  $(this).css({ border: "2px solid red" });
})

setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').append("<div class='yah''>123</div>");
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Do it in CSS using classes. The `css()` method is always a last resort which should be avoided where possible

Comment: `.load` event is deprecated (no doubt as it's confuses with `.load` method) - use `.on("load"...` - https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: this is badly require for me in `responsive` layout

Comment: That's all the more reason to do it properly in CSS, then.

Comment: The only way is via css classes.  `<style>.yah { border: 2px solid red }</style>` - all new `.yah` elements will be bordered.  Add/remove classes to change the border.

Comment: I tried this : `$('.yah').on('load', function(){
 $(this).css({border:"2px solid red"});
});` - But still fails

Comment: Can you create element, add css and then add it to DOM https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2445/

Comment: How are you "loading" your `.yah`?  In the question, you're *appending* html, **not** *loading* it.  (there's a subtle difference).  `.on("load"..` is when you load the content via ajax.  Doesn't look like you're using `load` at all, which is why it's not "working".

Comment: AFAIK there's no event called on `.append()`

Comment: @NenadVracar - I agree. But I am getting the element from backend. so it's loading from somewhere.. thanks to freedomn!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `MutationObserver` and watch for changes in `childList` and when specific node is added you can change its css.

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body')

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
        node = $(node);
        if (node.hasClass('yah')) node.css({
          'border': '1px solid red'
        })
      })
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(body, {
  childList: true
})

setTimeout(function() {
  body.innerHTML += "<div class='lorem'>123</div>"
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  body.innerHTML += "<div class='yah'>123</div>"
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  body.innerHTML += "<div class='ipsum'>123</div>"
}, 2500);

setTimeout(function() {
  body.innerHTML += "<div class='yah'>123</div>"
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use appendTo and css methods

```
$('<div class="yah">123</div>')
.appendTo(document.body)
.css({border: "2px solid red"});
```

or use parent html DOM change event

```
$('#parent_id').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    if($(".yah").length){
        $(".yah").css({border: "2px solid red"})
    }
})
```

Comment: I agree. But I am getting the element from backend

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` - works for me. But is it have browser compatibility?

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified not compatible with IE<9 You can use propertychange for IE<9.